# MaterialTextView cannot be casted into spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I am trying to create an adapter that utilizes data from spinners as well as text views.

```
        @Override
        public RecipeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
               View mView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,viewGroup,false);

                return new RecipeViewHolder(mView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecipeViewHolder recipeViewHolder, int i) {

                recipeViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(myrecipeList.get(i).getImage());
                recipeViewHolder.mTitle.setText(myrecipeList.get(i).getName());
                recipeViewHolder.mMeal.setSelection(getIndex(recipeViewHolder.mMeal, myrecipeList.get(i).getMeal()));
                recipeViewHolder.mDifficulty.setSelection(getIndex2(recipeViewHolder.mDifficulty, myrecipeList.get(i).getDifficulty()));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
                return myrecipeList.size();
        }
}
class RecipeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView mTitle
        Spinner mMeal, mDifficulty;
        CardView mCardView;

        public RecipeViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idIVCourseImage);
                mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVCourseName);
                mMeal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVCourseMeal);
                mDifficulty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVCourseDifficulty);
        }
```

GetIndex was supposed to convert it to string :

```
  public int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String meal) {
                for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
                        if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(meal)) {
                                return i;
                        }
                }
                return 0;
```

Get index 2 is the same thing but for difficulty

Here meal and difficulty are two values to be selected by the user from a spinner list.
Given below is my logcat:

```
2021-04-15 23:01:31.410 25171-25171/com.example.myrecipiebook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myrecipiebook, PID: 25171
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner
        at com.example.myrecipiebook.RecipeViewHolder.<init>(RecipeAdapter.java:86)
        at com.example.myrecipiebook.RecipeAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecipeAdapter.java:54)
        at com.example.myrecipiebook.RecipeAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecipeAdapter.java:23)
```

Comment: Post the layout used by the RecipeViewHolder

Comment: either `idTVCourseName` or `idTVCourseMeal` in your `item_list` layout is not a Spinner